# Replacing nested 'if' statements with (seemingly) equivalent 'elif' combined with 'not'

Tags: python, if-statement, return

1. 

```
 if statement1:
    if statement2:
       if statement3:
          return desired_action
       else:
          return action3
    else:
      return action2
 else:
   return action1
```

vs:
2.

```
 if not statement1:
     return action1
 elif not statement2:
     return action2
 elif not statement3:
     return action3
 else:
     return desired_action
```

I tend to prefer the second way, but for some reason it seems somewhat.. risky? or unreliable as much as the first method.

Also, do I really need that elif? I return when I reach a certain if.
Thank you.

Is there a convention or a standard?

Comment: `if s1 and s2: return desired if s3 else act3`  +  `if s1 and not s2: return act2`  `return act1`  ... this is all for personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent according to [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws): `NOT (A AND B) = (NOT A) OR (NOT B)`.

You `elif`s are required if you want to perform only an single alternative action. Without them (let's say all conditions are False), you would trigger every single alternative action.

Regarding which one of the two codes to chose is a bit subjective. The second one is more appealing and I would tend to go with this one.

*NB. your indentation of the second block was incorrect, I fixed it*

Comment: Yes they're equal, I was aiming more for : Is one method preferred in the industry by convention?
Also, the same quesiton about the multiple return statements?
Or should I store the values in a variable and return it at the end.. 
I'll edit my question
Thank you